# Presenting view controller from detached view controller is discouraged. Keeping User logged in issue

Tags: swift, userdefaults

I'm trying to have the user move to automatically go to the Home Screen and not have to log in again. Basically, to remember the user. I used User Defaults to save the user login info and put the listener for the key in the viewDidLoad of the first login page. I used an if statement to switch the view controllers but it doesn't work and prints (Presenting view controller from detached view controller is discouraged).

**LoginViewController**:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import AVKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    var videoPlayer:AVPlayer?
    
    var videoPlayerLayer:AVPlayerLayer?
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var Back: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordtextField: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupElements()
    
    }
    
    func dismissKeyboard() {
            //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
            view.endEditing(true)
        }
    func setupElements(){
        
        errorLabel.alpha = 0
        
        Utilities.styleTextField(emailTextField)
        Utilities.styleTextField(passwordtextField)
        Utilities.styleFilledButton(loginButton)
        
    }
    
  
    func validateFields() -> String?
    {
        //make sure fields are filled
        if emailTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" || passwordtextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == ""
        {
            return "Please fill all fields"
        }
        
      
        return nil
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    
        
        //creates a clean version of the text field
        let email = emailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let password = passwordtextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        
        let error = validateFields()
        //sign in user
       
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
    
            UserDefaults.standard.set(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid, forKey: "user_uid_key")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            if error != nil{
                self.errorLabel.text = "Invalid Username/Password try again."
                self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
                
        }
           
            else{
        
                let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.StoryBoard.homeViewController) as?
                    HomeViewController
                
                
                self.view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
                self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
                
                
                           }
        }
        
        
        //make sure all fields are filled
        
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        setUpVideo()
    }
  
    func setUpVideo(){
        //Get path to resource bundle
       let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "IMG_7211 2", ofType: "mov")
        
        guard bundlePath != nil else{
            return
        }
        //create the url from it
        
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: bundlePath!)
        
        //Create The video Player item
        let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
        //create the player
    
 
        videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
      
        //create the layer  
        videoPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer!)
        //adjust the size and frame
        
        videoPlayerLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: -self.view.frame.size.width*1.5, y:0, width: self.view.frame.size.width*4, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        
        view.layer.insertSublayer(videoPlayerLayer!, at: 0)
        
        //add and play
        
        videoPlayer?.playImmediately(atRate: 0.8)
    }
    
    
    
}
```

**ViewController**:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var videoPlayer:AVPlayer?
    
    var videoPlayerLayer:AVPlayerLayer?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var signUpButton: UIButton!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var logInButton: UIButton!
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if  UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "user_uid_key") != nil    {
            
            print("i see u")
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeViewController())
            navController.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
            self.present(navController, animated: false, completion: nil)  
            
        }
        
        else {
         
            let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.StoryBoard.homeViewController) as?
                ViewController
            
            
            self.view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
            self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
            
        
                // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        setupElements()     
    }

func showhomepage() {
    let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.StoryBoard.homeViewController) as?
        HomeViewController
    
    
    self.view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
    self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
}
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //Set up video in background        
        setUpVideo()
    }
    
    func setUpVideo(){
        //Get path to resource bundle
       let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Project", ofType: "mp4")
        
        guard bundlePath != nil else{
            return
        }
        //create the url from it
        
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: bundlePath!) 
        
        //Create The video Player item
        let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
        //create the player
        
        videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
        
        //create the layer
       
        videoPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer!)
      
        //adjust the size and frame
        
        videoPlayerLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: -self.view.frame.size.width*1.5, y:0, width: self.view.frame.size.width*4, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        
        view.layer.insertSublayer(videoPlayerLayer!, at: 0)
        
        //add and play
        
        videoPlayer?.playImmediately(atRate: 1)
    }

    func setupElements(){
        
        Utilities.styleFilledButton(signUpButton)
        Utilities.styleHollowButton(logInButton)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the SwiftUI in this code? I don't see it. Give me a clue why you've used the `swiftui` tag here. Thanks.

Comment: Also please take the time to format your code properly before asking a question about it. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any questions I can ask? And I pretty new to all this

Comment: There are way too many issues with the code you posted as I see and am not really sure of the logic as well, so am not gonna add the answer, but I can help you with the error you are facing, Error is very clear, In your `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` you tried to present a `HomeViewController` in your if condition, `viewDidLoad` is way too early to present a viewController from the current view controller, `viewDidLoad` means views are instantiated in memory not yet added to view hierarchy their frames are also not set, better place to put your if condition is `viewDidAppear`

Comment: If you are remembering the user I would suggest you change the root view controller itself with `HomeViewController` not really sure why would you present a `HomeViewController`, if the user is logged in I would suggest load a `HomeViewController` and set it as root view controller else load `LoginViewController` and set it as root view controller. On login success you are anyway setting `HomeViewController` as rootViewController. Also indentation, naming variables, classes are all over the place, might suggest you to check some open source/sample project to get the basic idea, all the best :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using Firebase. Do not store any login information in the User defaults. What you should do is create a blank view controller that will check if the user is signed in. If the user is signed it, it will present your HomeViewController; if the user is not signed in, it will present the login screen. You can also choose to perform these checks in your AppDelegate/SceneDelegate if you want to avoid the extra view controller.

- The empty ViewController should be the initial/root ViewController.
- You cannot present view controllers from inside `viewDidLoad`, use `viewDidAppear`.

Here is a basic example for the view controller way:

```
// in the new empty view controller, import FirebaseAuth

var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle!
    
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(false)
    handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
        if user != nil {
            // Go to Home Screen/ switch root
        } else {
            // Go to sign in screen/ switch root
        }
    }
}
```